# How to provision software using Vagrant without sudo

Tags: provisioning, sudo, vagrant

I'm trying to setup Vagrant virtual machines to support my learning through [Seven Databases in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/rwdata/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks). I'm provisioning software using basic shell scripts which performs appropriate actions within a sudo environment. However, I'm using the vagrant user to run the tutorials, and would like the provisioning to install the appropriate node / NPM modules as Vagrant, rather than through sudo.

My current npm command is the last line in this provisioning script, but the module is unavailable when vagrant tried to execute node scripts.

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential
apt-get -y install tcl8.5
wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.0-rc3.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-2.6.0-rc3.tar.gz
cd redis-2.6.0-rc3
make
make install
make test
mkdir /etc/redis
mv redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
sed -i.bak 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/redis/redis.conf
sed -i.bak 's/daemonize no/daemonize yes/g' /etc/redis/redis.conf
sed -i.bak 's/dir .\//dir \/var\/lib\/redis/g' /etc/redis/redis.conf

cd src/
wget https://raw.github.com/gist/1053791/880a4a046e06028e160055406d02bdc7c57f3615/redis-server
mv redis-server.1 /etc/init.d/redis-server
mv redis-cli /etc/init.d/redis-cli
chmod +x /etc/init.d/redis-server
sed -i.bak 's/DAEMON=\/usr\/bin\/redis-server/DAEMON=\/usr\/local\/bin\/redis-server/g'     /etc/init.d/redis-server 
useradd redis
mkdir -p /var/lib/redis
mkdir -p /var/log/redis
chown redis.redis /var/lib/redis
chown redis.redis /var/log/redis
update-rc.d redis-server defaults
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
cd /etc/init.d/
echo ./redis-cli 
echo http://blog.hemantthorat.com/install-redis-2-6-on-ubuntu/

apt-get -y install python-software-properties python g++ make
add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update
apt-get -y install nodejs

npm install hiredis redis csv
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply set `privileged` to `false` in your VagrantFile like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    ...
    config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "script.sh"
    ...
end
```

Comment: Super helpful when you've got an `npm install` to do during the provision. Note that you'll need to add `sudo` to your `apt-get` and other su-level commands in the provisioner with privileged mode off.

Answer (score 6):

The shell provision runs as the `root` user. If you with to run as the `vagrant` user, you can do something like this:

```
sudo -u vagrant npm install hiredis redis
```

..or for multiple lines:

```
sudo -u vagrant << EOF
[...]
npm install hiredis
npm install redis
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use npm install -g to install it globally in the vm?

Answer (score -1):

sed -i 's/.*requiretty$/Defaults !requiretty/' /etc/sudoers